# Convert array with same key in object

Tags: typescript, object

I have an array and I wanna to convert it into an object grouped by the same key(that is just a number)

```
let array = [

   {"2": {
       "5": {
         "valore": "COLORE 1",
         "obbligatorio": null
        }
     }
   },
    {"2": {
       "20": {
         "valore": "MATERIALE 2",
          "obbligatorio": true
      }
    }
   },
   {"2": {
        "21": {
           "valore": "LUNGHEZZA 2",
            "obbligatorio": true
        }
   }},
  {"3": {"6": {"valore": "MATERIALE 4","obbligatorio": true}}}]
```

My purpose is to transform the array in object and to group by the same key, like this:

```
"2": {
  "5": {
    "valore": "COLORE 1",
    "obbligatorio": null
  },
  "20": {
    "valore": "LUNGHEZZA 2",
    "obbligatorio": true
  },
  "21": {
    "valore": "MATERIALE 3",
    "obbligatorio": true
  }
},
"3": {
  "6": {
    "valore": "MATERIALE 4",
    "obbligatorio": true
  }
}
```

The problem is when I try to convert:

```
let obj = Object.assign({}, ...array);
```

It's group by just two values:

"2": {the last value}
"3": {the value of 3}

How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: `let array` is the correct array? there is an issue with the syntax as an array element

Comment: yes, copy paste problem. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array = [{
    "2": {
      "5": {
        "valore": "COLORE 1",
        "obbligatorio": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "2": {
      "20": {
        "valore": "MATERIALE 2",
        "obbligatorio": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "2": {
      "21": {
        "valore": "LUNGHEZZA 2",
        "obbligatorio": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "3": {
      "6": {
        "valore": "MATERIALE 4",
        "obbligatorio": true
      }
    }
  }
]

const output = array.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const key = Object.keys(val)[0]
  if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = {}
  acc[key] = { ...acc[key], ...val[key]}
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(output)
```